# How to handle different Symfony projects with one SSO

Tags: symfony, architecture

I have two Symfony projects:
#1 project is storing user informations and groups (with user rights in it), and the project #2 is using theses user informations and groups informations and storing other data (like books and articles, created by user (referenced by userId stored in #1)).

The main issue is to retreive the users informations into the #2 project like firstname. How to do this properly? What is the best way to achieve this?

- Create a messenger which updates project #2 when data are changed in project #1 + Symfony bundles with users and all linked entities (so users data are copied between all the project)
- Have same database
- Do REST calls

It's not really a Symfony related problem, but an architectural...

Comment: If I understand correctly if a user changed their firstname in the user-application it should be send to other applications so those application can update the firstname in their database? 
Or do you want to know about the user in the other applications in a manner you can trust?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the setup, but if I understand correctly, this could be a possible option.

You could create a small Symfony project for authentication. This project would handle the login method and roles. With this data you can create a JWT token. That can be used in your other applications. The token can contain basic information such as username, email, roles etc

Example.

[www.yourapplication.com](http://www.yourapplication.com)
-> user not loggedin -> redirect to authenticator example -> authenticator.yourapplication.com/login?callback_url=www.yourapplication.com/login

In the authenticator.yourapplication.com application
-> handle login -> generate jwt token -> redirect back to callback url with params [www.yourapplication.com/login?jwt=ey......](http://www.yourapplication.com/login?jwt=ey......).

Back in [www.yourapplication.com](http://www.yourapplication.com)
validate jwt token and set user logedin when valid.

for security you can do the first request with post request and some more security checks.